# Error on uploading file in java to ftp server

Tags: java, file-upload, image-upload, java-server

When I try to upload files to ftp server, I get errors. The server is a remote server but it offers ftp access. This is the code I am using

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package fileuploaddemo;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileUploadDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        client.connect("ftp.adress.comlu.com");
        client.login("username", "mypass");

        //
        // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
        //
        String filename = "D:/xxx/screen0.png";
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

        //
        // Store file to server
        //
        client.storeFile(filename, fis);
        client.logout();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the program output. Nothing gets uploaded and all I get are these lines.

```
run:
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175)
at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:310)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:290)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:479)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:552)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.port(FTP.java:877)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:709)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:565)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:557)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1795)
at fileuploaddemo.FileUploadDemo.main(FileUploadDemo.java:29)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I had to add: netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable In command promp in admin rights. This is a Java 7 bug on Windows machines.

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
client.enterLocalPassiveMode()
```

before you initiate transfer. I suspect you need to get into PASV mode for data transfer. This can happen in case you are behind a router (NAT) or a firewall. The FTP server will try to connect to you for data connection by default, which means you start listening on some port and invite server to connect to it for transfer of data. But in case you are behind firewall or router, the server cannot connect to you directly. PASV mode instructs FTP server to instead open a port on server for transfer and the client connects to it.

Comment: I added the line before trying to store the file on server and now it said  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: I believe it needs to be called before calling connect instead. Try that check the javadoc http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalPassiveMode()

Comment: @Karuvägistaja can you post the new Exception? Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Solved
I had to add:
    netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
In command promp in admin rights. This is a Java 7 bug on Windows machines.

Comment: @Karuvägistaja I think you should mention your comment in your answer as my problem also got solved by using this command. It will be very helpful to other users if you put your comment as your answer. Btw thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the stack trace one sees that the file is transfered as TEXT, not BINARY, which possibly alters the file, and cannot deal with NUL etc.

```
  client.type(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

But especially @Kal is right.

Comment: it says cannot find variable FTP and Kal's solution didn't change anything.

Comment: You can use FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE. Class FTPClient extends FTP where the constant is defined. Sorry that Kal's solution did not work; it sounded plausible, as your code looks okay.

Comment: Solved I had to add: netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable In command promp in admin rights. This is a Java 7 bug on Windows machines